# How add new lines between rows and start and end position of the csv file

Tags: shell-script, shell, aix

The below input data contains table attribures with header information. 
The expected output is given below as well where the header and newline with intended text. This is expected as and when there is a change in the table name.

### Input Data

```
Table,Host,Database,Schema,column
DEPT,My Host,My Database,Integration,Deptno
EMP,My Host,My Database,stage,emp_no
EMP,My Host,My Database,stage,emp_name
```

### Expected Output:

```
+++ Database Column - begin ++
Table,Host,Database,Schema,column
DEPT,My Host,My Database,Integration,Deptno
+++ Database Column - end +++
+++ Database Column - begin ++
Table,Host,Database,Schema,column
EMP,My Host,My Database,stage,emp_no
EMP,My Host,My Database,stage,emp_name
+++ Database Column - end +++
```

Comment: I can't really see a logic in the transformation between input and output. Could you describe a bit about what's happening?

Comment: Hi,Because of formating issue data not appeared as expected.Now I have updated body of the question.

Comment: It's unclear whether the data is _actually_ double-spaced (ever second line empty).  Indent the data by four spaces or add  ```  on otherwise empty lines before and after.

Comment: Actual input data doesnt have any empty lines. I have added empty lines other wise multiple rows appearing as single row in the body.

Comment: I fixed the formatting.

Comment: Input data and expected output should not have any empty line between the lines. I have added empty lines between the lines other wise multiple lines appearing as single line in body.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN {
    table = 1#st field
    begin = "+++ Database Column - begin +++"
    end = "+++ Database Column - end +++"
  }
  NR == 1 {begin = begin "\n" $0; next}
  $table != last_table {
    if (NR > 2) print end
    print begin
    last_table = $table
  }
  {print}
  END{if (NR > 1) print end}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{
                $header="+++ Database Column - begin +++"; 
                $footer="+++ Database Column - end +++";
            }
            if($.==1){
                $header.="\n$_"; 
                next;
            } 
            print "$header$_$footer\n"' file 
+++ Database Column - begin +++
Name,Host,Database,Schema,Table,Description,ODBC Type,Data Type,Native Type
Deptno,My Host,My Database,Integration,Dept,Description of Column,INTEGER,INT16,Number
+++ Database Column - end +++
+++ Database Column - begin +++
Name,Host,Database,Schema,Table,Description,ODBC Type,Data Type,Native Type
empno,My Host,My Database,stage,emp,Description of Column,INTEGER,INT16,Number
+++ Database Column - end +++
+++ Database Column - begin +++
Name,Host,Database,Schema,Table,Description,ODBC Type,Data Type,Native Type
empname,My Host,stage,emp,Description of Column,VARCHAR,STRING,Text
+++ Database Column - end +++
```